# Is it possible to implement hypothetical std::merge_unique for InputIterators?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I tried to implement `merge_unique` having the next semantics: it should merge two sorted ranges (here - in non-decreasing order), copying only the first of equivalent elements if any in any of both ranges (from the first one if both have equivalent elements). It is like `std::merge` of two ranges then `std::unique` of resulting range, but in one pass.

```
template<typename ForwardIterator1, typename ForwardIterator2, typename OutputIterator>
OutputIterator merge_unique(ForwardIterator1 first1, ForwardIterator1 last1,
                            ForwardIterator2 first2, ForwardIterator2 last2,
                            OutputIterator result)
{
    using FirstTypeRef = typename std::iterator_traits<ForwardIterator1>::reference;
    using SecondTypeRef = typename std::iterator_traits<ForwardIterator2>::reference;
    while (first1 != last1 && first2 != last2) {
        FirstTypeRef&& value1 = *first1;
        SecondTypeRef&& value2 = *first2;
        if (value2 < value1) {
            while (++first2 != last2 && !(value2 < *first2));
            *result++ = std::forward<SecondTypeRef>(value2);
        } else {
            while (++first1 != last1 && !(value1 < *first1));
            if (!(value1 < value2)) {
                while (++first2 != last2 && !(value2 < *first2));
            }
            *result++ = std::forward<FirstTypeRef>(value1);
        }
    }
    while (first1 != last1) {
        FirstTypeRef&& value1 = *first1;
        while (++first1 != last1 && !(value1 < *first1));
        *result++ = std::forward<FirstTypeRef>(value1);
    }
    while (first2 != last2) {
        SecondTypeRef&& value2 = *first2;
        while (++first2 != last2 && !(value2 < *first2));
        *result++ = std::forward<SecondTypeRef>(value2);
    }
    return result;
}
```

It works fine for iterators up to `ForwardIterator` iterator category, but I can't make it work for `InputIterator`s, because they does not provide so called "multipass guarantee": https://godbolt.org/z/3Gze46Geo.

Is it theoretically somehow possible to implement `merge_unique` for `InputIterator`s?

Comment: By storing value?..

Comment: It would be better to describe in words the semantics you want, and not post a blob of code and just call it "straightforward".

Comment: @T.C. done. I sure it is straightforward: it is like `std::merge` then `std::unique` in one pass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically [how `unique_copy` does it](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique_copy#Notes). The two strategies when you can't reread the input are

- reread the output, if that is possible and the write is value-preserving;
- making a temporary copy of the value.

Answer (score 1):

Very interesting task, thanks! Decided to implement from scratch my own solution of your task suitable for not just two iterator ranges but many (even dozens), i.e. merging very many sorted iterables.

Used three technologies: Max-Heap [std::push_heap()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/push_heap)/[std::pop_heap()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/pop_heap) (read about it [in Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure))) for finding out which iterable range should give next value, Set [std::set](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) to find out if values repeat, my own `IteratorWrapper<T>` which gives virtual interface to abstract-out different types of iterators.

My algorithm is as following:

1. My `MergeUnique<T>()` accepts any kind of heterogeneous iterator-pairs, of any iterator type (it is enough for iterator to support `++` and `*` and `==`). Any amount of pairs is accepted, even a dozen. These pairs of iterators are passed as `std::vector<std::pair<IteratorWrapper<T>, IteratorWrapper<T>>>`.
2. My `IteratorWrapper<T>` signifies any iterator that gives type `T` when dereferenced through `*`. This templated class implements a special virtual (abstract) interface which with the help of [std::shared_ptr](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) allows for IteratorWrapper to absorb inside any type of iterator, having common class `IteratorWrapper<T>` allowing to store different iterators within same vector.
3. Merge algorithm does following things:

   1. On input we have N pairs of iterators [begin, end) signifying iterable ranges. There can be more than two pairs, even a dozen or so. Each iterator on dereferencing gives object of type T.
   2. We create a Min-Heap (using [std::push_heap()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/push_heap)) containing N elements, pointing to first elements of each iterator range. If some ranges have same first elements, then they are skipped till only unique elements reside in Min-Heap. Also [std::set](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) is used to figure out if our elements repeat in different ranges or are unique.
   3. While heap is not empty we do:

      1. Get top (minimal) element and save it. Pop-out top element of min-heap through [std::pop_heap()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/pop_heap). Erase this element from `std::set` too.
      2. Top element is outputted to output iterator as answer. This top element is the smallest element pointed by current iterators, hence outputted values go in sorted ascending order.
      3. Try taking next elements from iterable range where top element was located, try elements going right after the top element. While elements are present in `std::set` we skip them, to remind std::set shows what elements are currently contained in min-heap.
      4. When next element is unique then we place it into min-heap through [std::push_heap()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/push_heap).
      5. If some iterable range reaches `end` of range, then we're finished with this range, hence min-heap becomes smaller by 1 in size.

My algorithm above has time complexity `O(Log2(N) * Total_Number_of_Elements_in_All_Iterable_Ranges)`, to remind N means number of ranges. `Log2` comes from the fact that adding/removing from min-heap and/or std::set takes Log2 time.

As optimization, I don't copy or move iterators here and there, but instead my min-heap and std::set both are based on lightweight `size_t` which is just light reference to index of referenced iterable range, this size_t is enough to do all things. Hence passed iterators can be very heavy to copy, but still this will not affect speed at all.

For testing purposes I created tests using small class `IntStr` which represents pair of integer and string. I used iterators from following Std containers types: [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), [std::list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list), [std::deque](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque), [std::set](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set). All these containers have different types of iterators (with different class names), but still all they work inside single MergeUnique call.

My test passes pairs of int+str inside 4 sorted ranges. Pairs are compared only by integer value, only it matters, while string is used just as a comment to show out which integer value was used among all equal values, if inside a range equal ranges are met.

See examples of usage inside `main()` function.

[Try it online!](https://godbolt.org/z/o4nG67zTM)

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <functional>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

#include <list>
#include <deque>
#include <string>

using std::size_t;

template <typename T>
class IteratorWrapper {
    struct WrI {
        virtual void operator ++ () = 0;
        virtual bool operator == (WrI const & other) const = 0;
        virtual T const & operator * () const = 0;
        virtual ~WrI() {}
    };
    template <typename It>
    struct Wr : public WrI {
        template <typename P>
        Wr(P && x)
            : pit_(std::make_shared<It>(std::forward<P>(x))) {}

        void operator ++ () override { ++*pit_; }
        bool operator == (WrI const & other) const override {
            return *dynamic_cast<Wr const &>(other).pit_ == *pit_;
        }
        T const & operator * () const override { return **pit_; }

        std::shared_ptr<It> pit_;
    };

public:
    template <typename Q>
    IteratorWrapper(Q && x)
        : wri_(std::make_shared<Wr<Q>>(std::forward<Q>(x))) {}

    void operator ++ () { ++*wri_; }
    bool operator == (IteratorWrapper const & o) const
        { return *wri_ == *o.wri_; }
    bool operator != (IteratorWrapper const & o) const
        { return !(*this == o); }
    T const & operator * () const { return **wri_; }
    T const * operator -> () const { return &**wri_; }

private:
    std::shared_ptr<WrI> wri_;
};

template <typename T, typename OutIt,
    typename It = IteratorWrapper<T>>
OutIt MergeUnique(std::vector<std::pair<It, It>> its, OutIt out) {
    auto Cmp = [&](size_t a, size_t b){
        return *its[a].first > *its[b].first;
    };
    std::vector<size_t> heap;
    std::set<size_t, decltype(Cmp)> contains(Cmp);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < its.size(); ++i) {
        while (its[i].first != its[i].second &&
                contains.count(i))
            ++its[i].first;
        if (its[i].first != its[i].second) {
            contains.insert(i);
            // Push Min-Heap
            heap.push_back(i); std::push_heap(heap.data(),
                heap.data() + heap.size(), Cmp);
        }
    }
    while (!heap.empty()) {
        // Pop Min-Heap
        size_t const i = heap.front(); std::pop_heap(heap.data(),
            heap.data() + heap.size(), Cmp); heap.pop_back();
        T const val = *its[i].first;
        contains.erase(i);
        *out = val;
        ++out;
        ++its[i].first;
        while (its[i].first != its[i].second && (*its[i].first == val
                || contains.count(i)))
            ++its[i].first;
        if (its[i].first != its[i].second) {
            contains.insert(i);
            // Push Min-Heap
            heap.push_back(i); std::push_heap(heap.data(),
                heap.data() + heap.size(), Cmp);
        }
    }
    return std::move(out);
}

struct IntStr {
    IntStr(int _i, std::string _s)
        : first(_i), second(_s) {}

    bool operator == (IntStr const & o) const
        { return first == o.first; }
    int operator <=> (IntStr const & o) const
        { return first -  o.first; }

    int first = 0;
    std::string second;
};

int main() {
    std::vector<IntStr> w = {{2, "w2a"}, {5, "w5a"},
        {11, "w11a"}};
    std::list<IntStr> x = {{3, "x3a"}, {5, "x5a"}, {7, "x7a"},
        {7, "x7b"}};
    std::deque<IntStr> y = {{5, "y5a"}, {5, "y5b"}, {5, "y5c"},
        {7, "y7a"}, {11, "y11a"}, {13, "y13a"}};
    std::set<IntStr> z = {{3, "z3a"}, {7, "z7a"}, {7, "z7b"},
        {7, "z7c"}, {13, "z13a"}, {17, "z17a"}, {17, "z17b"}};

    std::vector<IntStr> res;
    
    MergeUnique<IntStr>({
        {w.cbegin(), w.cend()},
        {x.cbegin(), x.cend()},
        {y.cbegin(), y.cend()},
        {z.cbegin(), z.cend()}},
        std::back_inserter(res));
        
    for (size_t j = 0; j < res.size(); ++j)
        std::cout << res[j].first << "_" << res[j].second << ", ";
}
```

Input:

```cpp
    std::vector<IntStr> w = {{2, "w2a"}, {5, "w5a"},
        {11, "w11a"}};
    std::list<IntStr> x = {{3, "x3a"}, {5, "x5a"}, {7, "x7a"},
        {7, "x7b"}};
    std::deque<IntStr> y = {{5, "y5a"}, {5, "y5b"}, {5, "y5c"},
        {7, "y7a"}, {11, "y11a"}, {13, "y13a"}};
    std::set<IntStr> z = {{3, "z3a"}, {7, "z7a"}, {7, "z7b"},
        {7, "z7c"}, {13, "z13a"}, {17, "z17a"}, {17, "z17b"}};
```

Output:

```
2_w2a, 3_x3a, 5_y5a, 7_z7a, 11_w11a, 13_y13a, 17_z17a,
```